# Use setTimeout for query Collection in Meteor

Tags: meteor, settimeout

I defined a Collection in the model.js like this:

```js
People = new Meteor.Collection("people");
```

Here's the code in main.js:

```js
function test2(){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(People.find().fetch()));
  setTimeout(test2,5000)
}
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  if(People.find().fetch().length === 0){
    var tom = {name:"Tom",age:18};
    People.insert(tom);
  }

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    test2();
  });
}
```

Here are the errors I get:

[image]

I  want to Meteor execute some CRUD on the Collection automatically at set intervals. So I'm using `setTimeOut`, but it seems to be difficult.

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: And I try to use Events class of Noe.js ,but the errors is the same:      <pre>events = __meteor_bootstrap__.require('events');
 var emitter = new events.EventEmitter();
 emitter.on('MySyncEvent', function() {
  test();
 });
 setInterval(function(){
  emitter.emit('MySyncEvent')
 },10000);</pre>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Meteor.setTimeout](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_settimeout) instead:

```
Meteor.setTimeout(test2,5000)
```

On the server meteor code is run using fibers to let your write synchronous code, javascript's timeout has to let its callback fire in a fiber too, especially if it contains meteor code.